# c# eval function

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this code in a vb.net page and it works just fine.  When I tried to copy and paste the html into a c# page, it doesn't work, not sure why, any clue?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decal Expiration Date"                                                       SortExpression="ExpirationDate">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#DisplayExpirationDate(Eval("DecalID"))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the asp:Template field is in a gridview.  I have the function `DisplayExpirationDate` in the code behind.  On the aspx source page, it underlines the line `<%#DisplayExpirationDate(Eval("DecalID"))%>` and tells me that the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments.  It works on the VB page, but not on the c# page.

Any help, explanation appreciated.

Comment: You're going to atleast give us the signature of the DisplayExpirationDate() method.  Your input is not of the right type.  Probably will need to be casted as an int if I had to take a guess.

Comment: I fixed it by using:   <%#DisplayExpirationDate(Eval("DecalID").ToString())%>

Comment: DisplayExpirationDate has an input variable named DecalID which is of type string?

Comment: Oh no, you have string param for that?

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast your value to the appropriate data type, e.g.

```
<%#DisplayExpirationDate((string)Eval("DecalID"))%>
```

The method must accept an object of type object otherwise. In VB.NET it works as long as you compile without compiler option strict.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET has a very...errmm...*forgiving* [implicit cast (and other, mostly unrelated, but just as vexing) setting named `Option Strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This defaults to Off, so it will try - at runtime - to convert the return of `Eval` (which is `System.Object`) to whatever type your function requires.

C# takes the other approach, and makes you specify the cast. So, you should change it to:

`<%#DisplayExpirationDate((string)Eval("DecalID"))%>`

Note that, *if* you require a string, you can also do:

`<%#DisplayExpirationDate(Eval("DecalID").ToString())%>`

but, that's not exactly the same thing - it will fail if the value is `null` (`Nothing` in VB.NET), but succeed if it's `DBNull`. The previous version will do the *opposite*. I generally consider the haphazard use of `DBNull` and `ToString` as sloppiness, so I strongly encourage the first pattern and appropriate `DBNull` checking if warranted.